# Security between Android and PHP webservice

Tags: php, android, security, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have an Android application and an in-app purchase.

I want to post the user_id s of the ones that purchase it to my remote database via a php file.

I know some clever users can listen to the network and see the address of my php service. They may even find out what variables I am sending. 
I know how to encrypt user_id of course. I can do it either with RSA or AES. But I need to keep public key for RSA in the app.

Here is my question: A more clever attacker can easily get the public key and encrypt his user id and post to my web service. How do I prevent this scenario?

Comment: Why do you want to submit PII from the user's device to your server anyway? If this is for licensing/DRM, did you check out [Google Play Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/) yet?

Comment: Yes I already did. Since I am using in-app purchases, I have followed the in-app purchases licensing guide. In that guide, it clearly says that contacting google play to check items that is purchased must done only once at application Install. I cannot check everytime a user open the app right?

Comment: Furthermure, the guide is for paid apps mostly. My app is free and has in-app purchases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem. What i need is to do signature verification on the server side. I just need to send the signature and the signed data to my server.
No one can trick these data. They are coming directly from google.
Once the signature verification is complete I just added the user to my mysql table.

Comment: "Once the signature verification is complete I just added the user to my mysql table." - what stops the bad guy from adding the user to the mySQL table without performing verification?

Comment: They cannot just edit the mySQL table. PHP file does the signature verification and then add the user to the table.